# Dart (Flutter) : Mostrar un AlertDialog cuando la variable llegue a 0

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo un problema que me está volviendo loco...

No debe ser algo dificil pero estoy en mis primeros pasos con dart y no doy con la tecla.

Tengo un Widget el cual es un Timer, y quiero que cuando la cuenta del Timer llegue a 0 (cero) abra un dialog en el que te indique que se te ha acabado el tiempo.

Adjunto el código del widget, no se por donde tirar para insertar el show

```
class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  const Timer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Timer> createState() => TimerState();
}

class TimerState extends State<Timer> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  String get countText {
    Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return '${count.inHours}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
    controller.reverse(from: controller.value == 0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (context, child) => Text(countText),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Aquí está el showDialog que querría introducir cuando la variable **countText** sea cero.

```
  showDialog<String>(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                  content: const Text('El tiempo se ha acabado'),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                                      child: const Text('OK'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ));
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del `initState` a tu controlador le tienes que agregar un `listener` para que pueda escuchar cuando el valor llegue a `0`, entonces, lo que puedes hace es esto:

```
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    controller.reverse(from: controller.value == 0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.value == 0) {
        alerta();
      }
    });
  }
```

Alerta viene a ser el `showDialog`:

```
    void alerta() {
    showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              content: const Text('El tiempo se ha acabado'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ));
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jonathan, me ha funcionado a la perfección!